# How to fill out missing time data by using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd data series like below. For some reasons, it doesn't have data through 2018-07-26 13:30:00 ~ 2018-08-03 15:45:00

```
13     2018-03-13 16:40:00      12   12.07          0       
14     2018-03-13 16:41:00      13   12.07          0       
15     2018-03-13 16:42:00      12   12.07          0       
 …
230000 2018-07-26 13:30:00      45   12.07          0
230001 2018-08-03 15:45:00      30   12.07          0
230002 ....
…
```

I wanted to fill these blank out with 0 and tried "pandas.Series.asfreq" like this

```
df1= df.asfreq("T",fill_value=0)
print(df1)
```

but it gave me a weird response like below.

```
1970-01-01       0    0    0
```

Could you teach me how to fill out those blanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, I believe you need to use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first, setting the index to your `datetime` column.

Here is a basic example, but you would substitute `'datetime_col'` for the actual name of your own datetime column:

```
# If necessary, cast datetime column to correct dtype
# df['datetime_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_col']) 

df_new = df.set_index('datetime_col').asfreq('T', fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: I think you are right! I thought I did but it seemed like I failed setting the index. Your code worked as I expected. Thank you so much!